# Filtering Parent-Child Rows Independently in AG-Grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

I am currently going through the documentation regarding filtering:
https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/tree-data/

In the "Example: Organisational Hierarchy" demo section example code, I added:

```
filter: 'agTextColumnFilter'
```

to each column.

However, when trying to filter for:
Job Title rows with "Exec" AND Organistion Hierarchy rows with "Erica" the resulting data shown is empty.
Is there a way to make the filtering independent such that Org Hierarchy rows with "Erica" are shown with any "Job Title" rows with "Exec" shown?

My goal is that parent rows i.e. Organisation Hierarchy are not affected by the filtering of other columns.

Demo Plnkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/vEAePeMCk2YsjrmQ?preview

Demo Video Example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-omH9SxTTQ